# Notify user page was modified if trying to exit, what's the technique?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If a user is on a page with a form, and they have edited something, and then try and navigate to another page, how can I notify them?

How do people do this?

Is it a matter of computing a hash of all the input fields and comparing if they are exiting the page?

Is there a on page unload event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like to only prompt the user if they've actually changed something. Something like this:

```
var changesMade = false;

function onDataChanged() {
    changesMade = true;
}

$('input:text, textarea, select').change(onDataChanged);
$('input:checkbox, input:radio').click(onDataChanged);

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    if (changesMade) {
        return 'Changes have been made. Are you sure you want to leave the page?';
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: but clicking doesn't mean it was changed?

Comment: Clicking doesn't necessarily mean that a checkbox or radio button was changed, but you could track that if you really wanted. I guess I should bill this as "only checking if there's been user activity".

Answer (score 0):

The `onbeforeunload` event:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    return 'Are you sure?';
});
```

On some browsers this displays the message, on other browsers the message is not shown. It does show a dialog with a `Leave` and a `Stay` button on all browsers though (as far as I know) so that the user can choose.

Answer (score 0):

Use `beforeunload` event of window.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        return confirm("Alert user");
    });
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether this has the desired effect. On Chrome, the confirm pops up, after which the page leaving dialogs pops up with either `true` or `false` as its contents.